# how do I figure out what jqGrid is sending over to the server before it is sent?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

using jqGrid and using Advanced Searching... but I want to snag the "query" that is being sent over before it is sent (so the user builds it once, I can "save it off" somewhere and then resend it later).

but I can't figure out how to grab it...  can anyone help??

Answer (score 2):

Try out the [loadBeforeSend](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) event